# Driving a 15V, 150W AC halogen

Tags: ac, transformer, step-down, halogen

I have a  [15V, 150W Quartz Tungsten Halogen](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000ONKFV2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)  and would like to make it work. So far I have found that it is driven using AC, so I believe I need an AC/AC step down transformer (if 220VAC is used)? If so, do I buy a specific one or do I make one myself? Though, I am not entirely sure if it is the correct approach.

Any relevant information is appreciated.

Comment: There are comercailly available transformers (real) and switch-mode "halogen-type" electronic converters for the purpose. If you don't have any experience working with 220 VAC, I would recommend you to stay away from atempting to wind one yourself.

Comment: While it can be driven with AC (and a commercial 230V/15V AC transformer is simplest) it'll run perfectly well off 15V DC too.

Comment: Unlike HID lamps, which will run on DC but with reduced lifetime due to uneven electrode erosion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF it is a 150W Tungsten filament operating at 15Vrms or dc, then the current at 4000'K is about 150W/15V=10A and the resistance is 15V/10A= 1.5 Ohms.

We know that that PTC characteristics for tungsten are 1:10 Ohms cold:hot thus the cold resistance should be 1.5Ohms/10= 150 milliohms which results in a surge current of 15V/0.15 Ohms = 100 A or 10x the hot current.  In order to minimize transformer losses the secondary winding DCR should be about the same order of cold filament resistance  or less , which help to reduce the surge current in half or less at the expense of 5% additional conduction losses.

side note

But if you need a regulated current limiter, these bulbs make great series current regulators with 10~20W power LEDs or 4x3W LEDS operating at 15 Vdc and work like PTC active Polyfuses when used with less than half of its voltage rating. So you can replace the 150W wasted halogen power with 20W 12V LEDs using 15Vdc ( if you had such a supply)

Answer (score 0):

If you use only a 220/15 transformer, any fluctuations on the power line may cause the lamp to blink or even to break it down. Instead, you can buy a 15VDC/10A (Or with higher current rating) SMPS. This can be more efficient and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a mains to 15VDC 200W supply fairly economically. I would not suggest using a 150W supply.

[image]
The bulb will run okay from DC, though life will be slightly shorter than on AC due to notching effects. Since it will be regulated DC it will probably be a wash or better.

You will need a ceramic high temperature socket for those bulbs- they run really hot. We use similar bulbs (with dimmer) in fiber optic microscope illuminators for inspection.

Also note that the bulb life is fairly short (**50 hours** rated) at full voltage. Life increases rapidly with lowered voltage (but light output drops rapidly too). Most switching supplies in that class have a pot that allows the voltage to be trimmed slightly (you can just see the top of the orange single-turn pot in the above photo, to the right of the terminal block0.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did notice that these bulbs may go over 500C, so I am grateful for ceramic socket suggestion. 
In addition, why do people use similar lights for microscopy? I would like to use it as a light source for hyperspectral imaging as Tungsten halogens are known to provide uniform illumination across spectrum.